# Why custom condition is not containing parent entity?

Tags: commerce, 9, plugins

I'm using:

- Drupal  9.1.7
- Commerce 2.24

I'm trying to create my custom condition (based on https://docs.drupalcommerce.org/commerce2/developer-guide/core/conditions). However parent entity is always NULL. Seems like parent entity is only working when I specify `commerce_order` as `entity_type` only, but I need `commerce_order_item`. `ParentEntityAwareInterface` and `ParentEntityAwareTrait` are in use. Debugging show that:

```
  public function evaluate(EntityInterface $entity) {
    $this->assertEntity($entity);
    /** @var \Drupal\commerce_order\Entity\OrderItemInterface $order_item */
    $order_item = $entity;
    /** @var \Drupal\commerce_promotion\Entity\PromotionInterface $promotion */
    $promotion = $this->parentEntity;
    //$promotion is NULL
    // rest of the code
  }
```

`$promotion` is always null.

Annotation:

```
 * @CommerceCondition(
 *   id = "myproj_product_condition",
 *   label = @Translation("Product chooser"),
 *   category = @Translation("Product chooser"),
 *   entity_type = "commerce_order_item",
 *   parent_entity_type = "commerce_promotion",
 *   weight = 9,
 * )
```

Comment: I looked at the code used by the *Commerce Core* module. I cannot say why `$this->parentEntity` would be `NULL`, but the explanation could be in [`Promotion::getConditions()`](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/commerce/-/blob/8.x-2.x/modules/promotion/src/Entity/Promotion.php#L271), [`Promotion::apply()`](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/commerce/-/blob/8.x-2.x/modules/promotion/src/Entity/Promotion.php#L590), and [`Promotion::applies()`](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/commerce/-/blob/8.x-2.x/modules/promotion/src/Entity/Promotion.php#L554).

Comment: See the comment on `Promotion::applies()`: *Filter the conditions just in case there are leftover **order item conditions** (which have been moved to offer conditions).* (Emphasis is mine.)

Comment: @apaderno I'm debugging and it show that my condition `evaluate()` method is running before `\Drupal\commerce\Plugin\Commerce\Condition\ParentEntityAwareTrait::setParentEntity`, so that's why parent entity is NULL. Strange.

Comment: `setParentEntity()` is not always called. For what I can see, reading the code, the only classes calling that method are `Promotion`, but only for *commerce_order* conditions, and `PaymentGateway`.

Comment: I don't understand what *which have been moved to offer conditions* would mean, in the code comment I quoted earlier. What happens when a module implements a condition that is associated to the `Promotion` class but asks to get a `OrderItem` instance as argument? Is there code that assigns those conditions to an instance of the `OfferItem` or `Offer` class instead of the `Promotion` class as the class annotation says?

Comment: That is essentially the reason why I haven't posted an answer: It's not clear to me what the Commerce Core code is doing, not at the point to show which code is assigning a condition to a class instance that is different to the one requested in the annotation.

Answer (score 0):

The docs note this:

> (If you want the Condition to apply to multiple parent entity types, you can leave this property unset; however, you will need to be careful in your evaluate() method implementation to check the type of the parent entity before accessing any of the parent entity's methods.)

So it seems the annotation would be:

```
 * @CommerceCondition(
 *   id = "myproj_product_condition",
 *   label = @Translation("Product chooser"),
 *   category = @Translation("Product chooser"),
 *   entity_type = "commerce_order_item",
 *   weight = 9,
 * )
```

and assert:

```
$promotion = $this->parentEntity;

if (check $promotion is a certain entity type) {
 ...
}
```

Clear your cache after updating the Annotation (and may have to re-create the Rule? unsure if it affects that). Beyond that it could be a bug in Drupal Commerce.

Comment: The annotation used from the OP isn't wrong. It's the same annotation used by the [`OrderItemQuantity`](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/commerce/-/blob/8.x-2.x/modules/promotion/src/Plugin/Commerce/Condition/OrderItemQuantity.php#L29) class, which also uses `$promotion = $this->parentEntity;` in its [`evaluate()`](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/commerce/-/blob/8.x-2.x/modules/promotion/src/Plugin/Commerce/Condition/OrderItemQuantity.php#L81) method. The error isn't setting both *entity_type* and *parent_entity_type*; if there is something wrong, it's something else.

Comment: The entity type in that example is different, though? `commerce_order` vs `commerce_order_item`?

Comment: I meant that the issue should be further investigated, to understand whether `$this->parentEntity` can always be used and whether there is an alternative.

Comment: @apaderno I see only examples of commerce_order + commerce_promotion, but condition can work with commerce_order_item as well according to docs

Comment: @Codium It does, but in that case, the condition doesn't get it's `parentEntity` set. I think I understood why that happens, looking at the methods I linked in the other comment I posted, but I still find something not clear.

Comment: @apaderno i'm investigating further, thanks for you help